# Call method of unknown class type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to do something like this, but I don't know how and I'm kind of lost

```
    foreach ( var type in cmdTypes )
    {
        if ( type.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == Name.ToLowerInvariant() )
        {
            return (Commands)type.execute(cmdParams);//<==Incorrect

        }
        else
        {
            //Command not found!
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

This class is a derived of `Commands`. This is the base class:

```
abstract class Commands
{
    internal abstract int execute(object[] myParameters );

    internal string Name;

    public Commands()
    {
        Name=this.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call the `execute()` for all classes that derive from `Commands`
How could I accomplish this?

**UPDATE:** I think is better if I explain what I want to archive. I'm trying to make a class call a method when I pass the class name as a parameter.

Comment: use `string.Equals(,,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @sehe: No; use `String.Equals(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a collection of *types* that you are trying to use as *instances*.   You need an *instance* of a type to call non-static methods on, which can be done by either casting or reflection.

If you want to *create* an instance from the type, use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
foreach ( var type in cmdTypes )
{
    if ( type.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == Name.ToLowerInvariant() )
    {
        Command cmd = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Command;
        if(cmd != null)  // cmd is a Command!
            return cmd.execute(cmdParams);
        else
            // what should you do?
    }
    else
    {
        //Command not found!
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have some general design issues, but your compile error is due to a missing parenthesis.

```
return ((Commands)type).execute(cmdParams);
```

Dot is higher presence (happens before) than casting.

With full quotations yours looks like the following:

```
return (Commands)(type.execute(cmdParams));
```

Which fails since it cannot find `execute` given what it knows about `type`.

Also note that you may want to look into why you are looking at the type name, `as` and `is` are safer and easier to implement.

```
var command = type as Commands;
if (command != null)
{
    return command.execute(cmdParams);
}
else
{
    //Command not found!
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should explain why.

Comment: Actually this doesnt fix it I just mistyped the () after fixing them I get.
Cannot convert type 'System.Type' to 'namespace.Commands' which is the original error.

Comment: @Termiux: Is `type` a `System.Type`? If so you will need to do some instantiation logic which isn't here. I was assuming it was a derivative of `Commands` since that was closer to being correct. Do you have an instance of the class somewhere or only the `System.Type`?

Comment: Yes as u said I was missing the instances =P

Answer (score 2):

You just need to cast first, before attempting to call `execute`:

```
return ((Commands)type).execute(cmdParams);
```

The way you have it written, it's attempting to call `execute` on the un-casted type, and then to cast the result to `Commands`.